# Ansible didnt pass down variables between files

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I was trying to use Ansible to put some jinja2 templates to a directory, e.g. `path/from/*.j2 to path/to/*.txt`.

In my `./defaults/main.yml`:

```
---

test_var:
  - a: 1
    b: 2
  - a: 10
    b: 20
```

In my `./tasks/main.yml`:

```
---

- name: "Copy file"
  include: copy-files.yml
  with_nested:
    - test_var
  loop_control:
    loop_var: test_loop
```

In my `./tasks/copy-files.yml`:

```
---

- name: "copy {{ test_loop }}"
  template:
    src: "{{ test_loop.0.a }}"
    dest: "{{ test_loop.0.b }}"
```

I got the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'unicode object' has no attribute 'b'"}
```

Then I used debug and saw that the variables went missing.

```
task path: ./tasks/main.yml
Wednesday 06 February 2019  01:15:10 +0000 (0:00:00.286)       0:00:04.308 ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2
        },
        {
            "a": 10,
            "b": 20
        }
    ]
}

TASK [./ : Copy files] ********
task path: ./tasks/main.yml
Wednesday 06 February 2019  01:15:11 +0000 (0:00:00.064)       0:00:04.373 ****

TASK [./ : debug] *******************************
task path: ./tasks/copy-files.yml
Wednesday 06 February 2019  01:15:11 +0000 (0:00:00.089)       0:00:04.463 ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "a",
        "b"
    ]
}
```

So what could be wrong here?
`ansible 2.1.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what could be wrong here?

There are a few things at play.

Foremost, you are missing the jinja substitution of your `with_nested:`; I have no earthly idea why you even got "a" and "b", since that is very clearly a `list` of `str` you fed to `with_nested:`. I believe you wanted `with_nested: "{{ test_var }}"`. It's possible ansible "helped" you because of the *incredibly, disturbingly* ancient version of ansible you're on, but a modern version doesn't auto-coerce that name into a variable, so be aware.

However, even fixing that won't solve your problem, since `with_nested:` wants a `list` of `list`, not a `list` of `dict`; as you can see from [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian), it is effectively calling `{{ with_nested[0] | product(with_nested[1]) }}` and [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of a `dict` is a `list` of `tuple` of its `.keys()`, which explains the "a" and "b" you're seeing

If you want `src` and `dest` to be the values of the `a` and `b` key respectively, then skip the pretense and construct the `with_nested:` that way:

```
with_nested:
- '{{ test_var | map(attribute="a") | list }}'
- '{{ test_var | map(attribute="b") | list }}'
```